# Replace Python List/Set implementation with custom one

Tags: python, list, metaclass

I currently write a source-to-source compiler from a language developed by a professor of mine to Python. It goes all well, but some of the language idiosyncrasies drive me mad. The source language has 1-indexed lists and different slicing rules, and Python uses (much saner) 0-indexed-lists.

Is there any way that I can replace the list implementation Python uses? The following gives the idea of what I want.

```
class MyList(list):
    # My implementation of 1-indexed lists
    pass

x = ["foo", "bar", "baz"] 
y = MyList(["foo", "bar", "baz"])

assert type(x) == type(y) # Should work
assert x[1] == "foo" # Should work
```

I want to use the syntax sugar python gives me with lists, instead of dealing with generating it on my own. I know I would normally never do that in real code, but in addition to my current need, I wonder about a nice and elegant solution. I think about either fiddling the metaclass of *list*, or changing its functions at runtime. Is there any way that I can do that AND extend still MyList from list, since it uses list methods under its hood?

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap a list in a class and implement special [container-related method names](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types) like `__len__` and `__getitem__`. Here's an idea of what you might implement:

```
class MyList(object):

  def __init__(self):
    self._data = list()

  def __getitem__(self, index):
    return self._data[index+1]

  def __len__(self):
    return len(self._data)
```

Comment: I already did that with MyList. I want that the python list syntax returns a MyList, not a list.

Comment: @reindeer That's not possible AFAIK... :-\